# Archivo Bat con problema de Login

Tags: cmd

tengo el sigiente Script este deberia ir dentro de otro programa el cual llamo desde tareas programadas el problema es que al hacerle doble click me indica login Fail

```
@echo off
echo user subdominio@midominio.com> ftpcmd.dat 
echo Clave>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo mput C:\*.txt>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat 
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.midominio.com 
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Quisiera  saber cual es el problema que tiene mi script o si hay alguno mejor estuve leyendo y buscando por google uno para meter en este otro Bat y no consegui.

```
@echo off 
:: Espera 
title AutoBackUp en 43200 Segundos 
color c1 
echo. 
echo Faltan segundos para iniciar proxima copia de Seguridad 
echo. 
::timeout /t 42600 
mkdir C:\Temporal\BackUp 
mkdir C:\BackUp\DataBase 
mkdir D:\BackUp\DataBase 
ECHO --autobackup > BackUp.sql 
echo USE Donadores  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE Donadores  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\Donadores.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE GM_Stuff  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE GM_Stuff  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\GM_Stuff.bak'; >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE OMG_GameWEB  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE OMG_GameWEB  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\OMG_GameWEB.bak'; >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_Billing >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_Billing  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_Billing.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_ChatLog  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_ChatLog  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_ChatLog.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_GMTool  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_GMTool  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_GMTool.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_GameData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_GameData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_GameData.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_GameDefs  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_GameDefs  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_GameDefs.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_GameLog  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_GameLog  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_GameLog.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_StatData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_StatData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_StatData.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_Statics  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO  >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_Statics  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_Statics.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo USE PS_UserData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
echo BACKUP DATABASE PS_UserData  >> BackUp.sql 
echo TO DISK = 'C:\BackUp\Database\PS_UserData.bak';  >> BackUp.sql 
echo GO >> BackUp.sql 
sqlcmd -S "localhost" -d PS_Billing -U Usuario -P Pass -i BackUp.sql  
pause
del /f /q BackUp.sql  
cls 
timeout /t 5  
cls 
echo. 
echo Comprimiendo Archivos. 
echo Buscando y comprimiendo desde WinRaR en 32 y 64 Bits 
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" A -R C:\Temporal\BackUp\BackUp-%DATE%-Rock.RAR "C:\BackUp\DataBase" 
cls 
echo Buscando y comprimiendo desde WinRaR en 32 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" A -R C:\Temporal\BackUp\BackUp-%DATE%-Rock.RAR "C:\BackUp\DataBase" 
cls 
@echo off
echo user subdominio@midominio.com> ftpcmd.dat 
echo Clave>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo mput C:\*.txt>> ftpcmd.dat 
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat 
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.midominio.com 
del ftpcmd.dat 
timeout /t 50 
rd /s /q "C:\BackUp" 
move C:\Temporal\BackUp\*.RAR D:\BackUp\Database  
cls 
set anio=%date:~6,4% 
set mes=%date:~3,2% 
set dia=%date:~0,2% 
set hora=%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2% 
ren D:\BackUp\DataBase "DataBase-%dia%-%mes%-%anio%-%hora%" 
echo. 
echo Carpeta a sido renombrada. 
echo. 
timeout /t 50 
cls 
rd /s /q "C:\Temporal" 
echo. 
echo Procedimiento realizado con Exito... 
echo. 
echo reiiciando 
timeout /t 50  
cls 
::goto espera 
Echo BackUP finalizado
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría con

```
@echo off

>"ftpcmd.dat" (
    echo open ftp.midominio.com
    echo user subdominio@midominio.com
    echo Clave
    echo bin
    echo mput C:\*.txt
    echo quit
)
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
```